# Getting error with OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect:

Tags: python, operating-system

I want to make a script (GUI) in which I have to convert my text to a png file with the handwriting
but I still get this error

I try with `"\\"` instead of `"\"` at path

I want to change its name every time I make a new file, because it replaces the old file with a new one

```py
   File "C:\Users\790\OneDrive\Desktop\scrisdemana\main.py", line 16, in click
os.rename(r'C:\\Users\\790\\OneDrive\Desktop\\handwriting\\here.png',r'C:\\Users\790\\OneDrive\Desktop\\handwriting\\handwriting_' + str(x) + '.png')
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\790\\\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\\\handwriting\\\\here.png' -> 'C:\\\\Users\\790\\\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\\\handwriting\\\\handwriting_2021-06-20 13:20:22.660063.png'
```

this is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import pywhatkit as pwt 
import os
import time
import datetime

#pwt.text_to_handwriting("text","C:\\Users\\790\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\scrisdemana\\here.png", [10, 10, 10])

def click():
    x = datetime.datetime.now()
    entered_text = textentry.get()#this will collect the text from the text entry box
    output.delete(0.0, END)
    definition = pwt.text_to_handwriting(entered_text,"C:\\Users\\790\OneDrive\\Desktop\\handwriting\\here.png", [10, 10, 10])
    os.rename(r'C:\Users\790\OneDrive\Desktop\handwriting\here.png',r'C:\Users\790\OneDrive\Desktop\handwriting\handwriting_' + str(x) + '.png')
    output.insert(END, definition.text)




#### main:
window = Tk()
window.title("Translator")
window.configure(background="cyan")

#create label
Label (window, text="Pune aici textul:", bg="cyan", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

#create a text entry box
textentry = Entry(window, width=30, bg="white")
textentry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="W")

#add submit button
Button(window, text="Convert", width=6, command=click) .grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="W")
#create another label
Label (window, text="Output:", bg="cyan", fg="black", font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="E")
#create a text box
output = Text(window, width=30, height=6, wrap=WORD, background="white")
output.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="E")
#the dictionary
my_compdictionary = ""

#####run the main loop


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can have colons in filenames.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)